# What is definition of ε-tubes?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, arzela-ascoli

I am studying The Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem by [pdf](http://www.bens.ws/papers/arzelaAscoli.pdf) , and I don´t understand what is definition of tubes in the sentence below.

> To prove the theorem, we will start by simplifying it: we show that
>   the closure of Φ is compact if Φ itself is totally bounded. The proof
>   of this lemma makes use of the fact that each function in the closure
>   set is a limit point of Φ and thus close to a function in Φ. Hence, if
>   Φ is **covered by a finite number of ε-tubes**, the closure set is covered
>   by ever so slightly wider tubes, centered about the same functions. In
>   addition, the closure set is complete, being a closed subset of a
>   complete space. The compactness of the closure set will follow
>   immediately, since a complete totally bounded set is compact in any
>   metric space.

Comment: The $\epsilon$-tube centred on a function $f$ is $$\left\{g\in C(I):\sup_{x\in I}|g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\right\}\;.$$ It’s the set of functions whose graphs lie in an open tube of radius $\epsilon$ with the graph of $f$ running through the centre of the tube.

Comment: Perhaps the $\epsilon$-tube around $f(x)$ is all functions $g$ such that $|g(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$?